# Lambda expression for multiple foreach loops

Tags: c#, lambda

I would like to run GetResults() on all possible combinations of groups, languages and TestEnum.  How can I re-write this code using lambda expressions to avoid using the foreach loops?

```
    public enum TestEnum
    {
        ONE,
        TWO,
        THREE
    }

    public static void Test1()
    {
        List<string> groups = new List<string>() { "group1", "group2", "group3", "group4" };
        List<string> languages = new List<string>() { "EN-CA", "FR-CA" };
        List<string> results = new List<string>();

        foreach (string group in groups)
        {
            foreach (string language in languages)
            {
                foreach (TestEnum enumval in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TestEnum)))
                {
                    results.Add(GetResult(group, language, enumval));
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public static string GetResult(string group, string language, TestEnum enumval)
    {
        return group + language + enumval.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Rather than calling `GetValues` and then getting the string value of that, you can just use `GetNames` (that is, unless your real code uses the actual values, not just the string representations).

Comment: I'd recommend the trial version of Resharper, which will convert them for you, which helped me learn very quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to agree with lazyberezovsky, query syntax is easier to read in this case, but here goes:

```
results = groups
  .SelectMany(group => languages
     .SelectMany(language => Enum.GetValues(typeof(TestEnum))
        .Cast<TestEnum>()
           .Select(enumValue => GetResult(group, language, enumValue))))
  .ToList();
```

Maybe with better indentation or line breaks it would look nicer...

Comment: query syntax is much clearer, my intent in the question was to use method syntax though, thanks

Answer (score 6):

I think query syntax here is better than lambdas:

```
results = (from g in groups
           from l in languages
           from e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TestEnum)).Cast<TestEnum>()
           select g + l + e).ToList();
```

Produces

```
group1EN-CAONE
group1EN-CATWO
group1EN-CATHREE
group1FR-CAONE
group1FR-CATWO
group1FR-CATHREE
group2EN-CAONE
group2EN-CATWO
group2EN-CATHREE
etc
```

Comment: I would say *clearer*, not *better*, given that they compile into the same thing.  But yes, this would look a lot uglier in method syntax.

Comment: @Servy thnaks, yes you are right, *cleaner* is appropriate word)

Comment: I agree as well that query syntax is much clearer, my intent in the question was to use method syntax so Ill go with that answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this solve your problem:

```
var results = (
    from @group in groups 
    from language in languages 
    from TestEnum enumval in Enum.GetValues(typeof (TestEnum)) 
         select GetResult(@group, language, enumval)).ToList();
```

Let me know if your need some explanation.